# error baseVisitor[type] is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, triggers, pipedream

#### Describe the bug

Welcome,
When I try to run this code in node.js I get an error

**Code:**

```
let OriginalTitle = Manga.prototype.title;

class Manga {

        name = getName()
        name_ar
        full_name
        chapter = getChapter();
        link = steps.trigger.event.link;
        role = "@All Series"
        title= steps.trigger.event.title;
        date = steps.trigger.event.date;constructor(){
    Compiler();
  }


  
  
}
//Mangas-------------------------------
var OnePiece = new Manga();
var JujutsuKaisen = new Manga();
var KaijuNo8 = new Manga();
var MadeInAbyss = new Manga();
var Kingdom = new Manga();
var HunterXHunter = new Manga();
var Berserk = new Manga();
var Boruto = new Manga();
var Umineko = new Manga();
var JOJO = new Manga();
//-------------------------------------

function getName() {
  let str = OriginalTitle;
  const A = "الفصل  ";
  const D = "من مانجا ";
  const F = "مترجم للعربية على موقع العاشق للمانجا";
  let a = str.indexOf(A) + A.length;
  let b = str.indexOf(D);
  let c = b + D.length;
  let d = str.indexOf(F);
  let name = str.substring(c, d);
  return name;
  }
function Compiler(){
  var Name = Manga.prototype.name;

  switch(Name) {
  case 'One Piece':
    if(getChapter(OriginalTitle)%1 == 0){
      OnePiece.name_ar = "ون بيس";
      OnePiece.role += " @One Piece";
      OnePiece.full_name = OnePiece.name_ar +" || "+OnePiece.name;
      
      break;
    }
    else {
      OnePiece.name_ar = "ون بيس ملون";
      OnePiece.chapter = Math.floor(getChapter(OriginalTitle));
      OnePiece.role += " @One Piece";
      OnePiece.full_name = OnePiece.name_ar + " || " +OnePiece.name;
      break;
    }
  case "Jujutsu Kaisen":
    JujutsuKaisen.name_ar = "جوجوتسو كايسن";
    JujutsuKaisen.role += " @Jujutsu Kaisen";
    JujutsuKaisen.full_name = JujutsuKaisen.name_ar+" || "+JujutsuKaisen.name;
    break;
  case "Kaiju No. 8":
    KaijuNo8.name_ar = "كايجو رقم 8";
    KaijuNo8.role += " @Kaiju No.8";
    KaijuNo8.full_name = KaijuNo8.name_ar+" || "+KaijuNo8.name;
    break;
  case "Made In Abyss":
    MadeInAbyss.name_ar = "ميد إن أبيس";
    MadeInAbyss.role += " @Made In Abyss";
    MadeInAbyss.full_name = MadeInAbyss.name_ar + " || "+MadeInAbyss.name;
    break;
  case "One Piece Colored":
    break;
  case "Kingdom":
    Kingdom.name_ar = "كينقدوم";
    Kingdom.role += " @Kingdom";
    Kingdom.full_name = Kingdom.name_ar+" || "+Kingdom.name;
    break;
  case "Berserk":
    Berserk.name_ar = "بيرزرك";
    Berserk.role += " @Berserk";
    Berserk.full_name = Berserk.name_ar+" || "+Berserk.name;
    break;
  case "Hunter X Hunter":
    HunterXHunter.name_ar = "هنتر × هنتر";
    HunterXHunter.role += " @Hunter X Hunter";
    HunterXHunter.full_name = HunterXHunter.name_ar +" || "+ HunterXHunter.name;
    break;
  case "Boruto: Naruto Next Generation":
    Boruto.name ="Boruto";
    Boruto.name_ar ="بوروتو";
    Boruto.role += " @Boruto";
    Boruto.full_name = Boruto.name_ar+" || "+Boruto.name;
    break;
  case "Umineko No Naku Koro ni Chiru Episode 7: Requiem of the Golden Witch":
    Umineko.name = "Umineko";
    Umineko.name_ar = "أومينيكو";
    Umineko.role += " @Umineko";
    Umineko.full_name = Umineko.name_ar +" || "+Umineko.name;
    break;
  case "JOJO’s Bizarre Adventure Part 9: The JOJOLands":
    JOJO.name = "JOJOLands";
    JOJO.name_ar ="جوجولاندز";
    JOJO.role += " @JoJo";
    JOJO.full_name = JOJO.name_ar+" || "+JOJO.name;
    break;
  default:
    return NaN;
  }
}
function getChapter() {
  
  let regex = /\d+/;
  let match = OriginalTitle.match(regex);
  if (match) {
    return Number(match[0]);
  }
  else {
    return null;
  }
}

export default defineComponent({
  async run({ steps, $ }) {
    
    $.export('Manga Name',Manga.prototype.name,
    'Manga Name AR',Manga.prototype.name_ar,
    'Full name',Manga.prototype.full_name,
    'Chapter',Manga.prototype.chapter,
    'Link',Manga.prototype.link,
    'Roles',Manga.prototype.role,
    'Full Title',Manga.prototype.toString,
    'Date',Manga.prototype.date) 
  }

})
```

**Code Error:**

`baseVisitor[type] is not a function`

````
TypeError: baseVisitor[type] is not a function
    at c (/var/task/node_modules/acorn-walk/dist/walk.js:29:24)
    at Object.base.ClassBody (/var/task/node_modules/acorn-walk/dist/walk.js:441:7)
    at c (/var/task/node_modules/acorn-walk/dist/walk.js:29:24)
    at Object.base.Class (/var/task/node_modules/acorn-walk/dist/walk.js:434:5)
    at c (/var/task/node_modules/acorn-walk/dist/walk.js:29:24)
    at Object.base.ClassDeclaration.base.ClassExpression (/var/task/node_modules/acorn-walk/dist/walk.js:430:82)
    at c (/var/task/node_modules/acorn-walk/dist/walk.js:29:24)
    at Object.skipThrough (/var/task/node_modules/acorn-walk/dist/walk.js:186:39)
    at c (/var/task/node_modules/acorn-walk/dist/walk.js:29:24)
    at Object.base.Program.base.BlockStatement (/var/task/node_modules/acorn-walk/dist/walk.js:198:7)```
````

**It's supposed to get me out of these lines the data I exported**

```
$.export('Manga Name',Manga.prototype.name,
    'Manga Name AR',Manga.prototype.name_ar,
    'Full name',Manga.prototype.full_name,
    'Chapter',Manga.prototype.chapter,
    'Link',Manga.prototype.link,
    'Roles',Manga.prototype.role,
    'Full Title',Manga.prototype.toString,
    'Date',Manga.prototype.date)
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.